# Formula for a section of a Gaussian distribution with 0.5 probability

Tags: probability

My question is, given a point 'a' on a Gaussian distribution what is the corresponding point 'b' such that the area under the curve between 'a' and 'b' equals 0.5.

The goal for this is to take a list of numbers whose values fit a normal distribution and create a second list which is as dissimilar as possible to the original while keeping the mean and stddev of the original.

If this were a polynomial distribution I would do the integration myself, but if I understand correctly Gaussian distributions can only be integrated in polar coordinate form which is well above my skill level.

I recognize that pulling values from a look up table would give a decent approximation of this function, and if that's the most practical solution it could work. However a mathematical solution would be ideal.

let me know if you have a way of approaching this problem, and thanks for your time.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Answer (score 1):

$|P(Z\le \frac{X_0-\mu}{\sigma}) - P(Z\le \frac{X_1-\mu}{\sigma}) = 0.5$

$P(Z\le c) = P(Z\le \frac{X_0-\mu}{\sigma}) -.5$

$ P(Z\le c) =\Phi^{-1}{( P(Z\le \frac{X_0-\mu}{\sigma}) -.5)} = c_0$

$ c=\frac{X_1-\mu}{\sigma} = c_0$

$x_1 = \mu + \sigma \times c_0$

If $x_0$ is given, then by this method, you can find $x_1$

Let us say X follows N(15,100)

You have $x_0 = 20$, You want to find $x_1$

$P(Z\le \frac{X_0-\mu}{\sigma}) = P(Z\le \frac{20-15}{10}) = P(Z\le.5)$

$P(Z\le 0.5) = 0.69146$

Find $\Phi^{-1}{( 0.69146 -.5)} = \Phi^{-1}{(0.19146)} = -0.87252$

$x_1 = 15 + 10 \times -.87252 = 6.2748$

Between $x_0$ and$x_1$, there is a $0.5$ probability of area covering the gaussian distribution.

def inverse_normal_standard_distribution(p: float) -> float:
    """Calculates the inverse of the standard normal distribution."""

```
# Probability must be between 0 and 1
if p < 0 or p > 1:
    return 0.00

a = [-39.96968, 220.96609, -275.92851, 138.35775, -30.66479, 2.50662]
b = [-54.47609, 161.58583, -155.69897, 66.801311, -13.28068]

q = p - 0.5
r = q * q

return (((((a[0] * r + a[1]) * r + a[2]) * r + a[3]) * r + a[4]) * r + a[5]) * q / (((((b[0] * r + b[1]) * r + b[2]) * r + b[3]) * r + b[4]) * r + 1)
```

To calculate P(Z < z)

Use the following code

function CDF(x:extended):extended;

var value,sum:extended;

```
i:integer;
```

begin

sum:=x;

value:=x;

for i:=1 to 100 do

```
begin

  value:=(value*x*x/(2*i+1));

  sum:=sum+value;

end;
```

result:=0.5+(sum/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(x*x)/2);

end;

So now you have both code for P(Z<=z) and $\Phi^{-1} (x)$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Could you demonstrate it in a practical example?

Comment: Ok, got it. But the only way I know of for finding P(Z≤x) or Φ−1(x) is via lookup table, which I already acknowledged as a possible solution in the original post.

Comment: You got the code for both functions and the method to find the complementary x